# Wikipedia API full text search: only return exact matches

Tags: php, wikipedia-api

Using the search functionality of the Wikipedia API :

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=This%20Is%20An%20Example&srwhat=text

I would like to only receive results which exactly match the string, however, that is not what is being returned.

How do I induce this behavior in the API?

Comment: Use quotation marks: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=%22This%20Is%20An%20Example%22&srwhat=text
(see the official documentation: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:CirrusSearch#Prefer_phrase_matches)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not much to add to what leo said: Wikipedia now uses the CirrusSearch extension, so when using the [search API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search) you must refer to https://mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:CirrusSearch#Prefer_phrase_matches which tells you to [use quotation marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=%22This%20Is%20An%20Example%22&srwhat=text&srlimit=1):

```
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "continue": {
        "sroffset": 1,
        "continue": "-||"
    },
    "query": {
        "searchinfo": {
            "totalhits": 1100
        },
        "search": [
            {
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Woman in a Purple Coat",
                "snippet": "costume, surrounded by a complex of abstract design and exotic color. <span class=\"searchmatch\">This</span> <span class=\"searchmatch\">is</span> <span class=\"searchmatch\">an</span> <span class=\"searchmatch\">example</span> of one of the final groups of oil paintings in Matisse's career, in",
                "size": 1347,
                "wordcount": 96,
                "timestamp": "2016-10-20T16:52:48Z"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```